# jquery mouseleave exclude browser vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is how I use the mouseleave jquery event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mouseleave(function(event)
    { 
        //do something
    });
});
```

1. Is there a way which this event will NOT be fire when a user scrolls
   down the page?
2. I noticed that the event is triggered by child elements also. Is there a way to remove child elements from binding with this event?

Thank you

Comment: 2. I've been told its not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966407/jquery-mouseleave-document-triggered-by-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

To stop prevent event propagation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mouseleave(function(e)
    { 
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Here you can find more information:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: This does solve the child-element issue... However, when the user uses the browser scrollbar the event is still triggered