# Jquery mouseleave document triggered by scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#desktop-subscribe-modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

I am trying to trigger a function when the mouse leaves the document window. The above code works fine in Firefox but in Chrome it is triggered when hovering over the page scrollbar.

Is there a way to exclude the scrollbar from the mouseleave function?

Comment: Could you update your code in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Found a fix for this, see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got around this issue by checking the mouse position when mouseleave is triggered. I only really need it to trigger when the mouse hovers above the viewport so I just check if the vertical position is < 0.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mouseleave(function(e){

        //Check mouse is above the viewport
        if(e.clientY < 0){
            $('#desktop-subscribe-modal').modal('show');    
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks! Without the `e.clientY < 0` section, it will also trigger on chrome autofill, which is equally as annoying. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar is technically outside the client window, so all browsers *should* do that. Some don't (so really, FireFox is wrong, not Chrome) :)

However the best solution is to use a replacement scrollbar ([Perfect scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) is my favourite). These use elements inside the page so will do what you want on all browsers (and look pretty cool too).